# Hangfire recurring job for Every first Monday of month

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cron, hangfire

I googled for help couldn't find help myself so asking a quick question on cron schedule with Hangfire.

How to set cron expression if I want to execute hangfire recurring job every first monday of every month?

The expression  1 9 * 1/1 1#1 does not work in hangfire (as it uses crontab syntax and 1#1 is throws exception.

I'm using CronGen from [here](https://github.com/hsal/cronGen) and modifying it to generate CronTab syntax valid for Hangfire.

Answer (score 3):

Since the first Monday of the month is always within the first seven days of the month, you can use this:

```
1 9 1-7 * 1
```

Comment: Nice workaround! What about "Last Friday of month" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it'll be possible with crontab syntax to do so.

You could use the following cron expression

```
1 9 * 1/1 1
```

and then inside your batch job check if it's the first Monday or not?

Comment: so if I fire and forget hangfire job, I do need to remember not to execute job (within the job) if its not first Monday? somebody must have come up with something already it's not that unique request or is it?

Comment: Maybe there's a way that I'm not aware of, have you considered filing a bug report/feature request with the hangfire devs?